# How to get the auto generated radio button id in Cypress which matches some text?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I got a list of records on the page, where the id's of the radio buttons are auto-generated. How to get the `autogenerated id` of a radio button in a table row where the row also contains some `name` column. My whole idea is to click on the correct radio button that matches the name in that table records.

The below cypress test finds the correct row matches with the name `VM Survey`, but I am not sure how to instruct cypress to click on the radio button in the same row;

```
cy.get('td:contains(" VM Survey ")').parents('.mat-table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').contains(" VM Survey ")
```

[image]

Comment: Just for some clarification, when you click on "mat-radio-46" you want to check to see if the label for the button is "VM Survey"?

Comment: That label/ name is not for that radio button, but its available in the table row. Would be better if it matched !

Comment: So you're already able to select the correct row? Now you just want to click the radio button in that row?

Comment: Yes I would like to click that radio button in that row

Comment: Ok cool I will try to help you with this

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult without having access to the code directly, but let's give it a try.

Ok since you already are able to select the correct row, you can declare a variable equal to that element:

```
const row = cy.get('td:contains(" VM Survey ")')
    .parents('.mat-table')
    .find('tbody')
    .find('tr')
    .find('td')
    .contains(" VM Survey ")
    .then($row => {
        debugger;
        // here you have access to the row variable 
        // you should be able to traverse the element
        //  to the radio button in the $row and .click()
    })
})
```

Comment: You will need to navigate the properties of `$row` to get to the button.

Comment: Were you able to find/click it?

Comment: Will try this and let you know

Comment: I have tried this way, but no success yet`.then($row => {
        //debugger;
        $row.parents('.mat-table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').find('mat-radio-button').click();
        
    })`